# Advice on remote logging for my Ionic / Cordova app?

Tags: cordova, logging, ionic-framework

Looking for advice on remote logging for my Ionic / Cordova app.

I'd like to be able to capture multiple user interaction events, as well as exceptions. I've leaning towards Loggly but wanted to see if anyone has already done this successfully with another solution?